# How can I differentiate between a freshly loaded form and the same form loaded after redirection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

I have a login form with the following fields -
Username
Password
Return Failure
Direct Login
When I click on submit all the fields are appended in the URL and it hits a JSP file.
After this,
Scenario 1: If login is a success, it is redirected to success page. This works
Scenario 2: If login fails, it is redirected to the **return failure URL value passed as parameter**. While redirecting it does not give any response.
**Question -**
1. How can I differentiate between loading a fresh form and form loaded after redirection?
2. I have to display a warning for invalid username and password before redirecting the page to returnfailure value and not during a fresh load of form.How can I do this?

```
Below is the code -  
**HTML**  

    <form name="formlogin" method="get" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();" class="form-wrapper">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="service-lable" style="font-family:Verdana;">Username</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" name="username" maxlength="30" size="30" class="required"/> <br/><br/>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="service-lable" style="font-family:Verdana;">Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="password"maxlength="30" size="30" class="required"/> <br/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="directlogin" id="directlogin" value="1"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="returnfailure" id="returnfailure" value="http://www.google.com"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit"  name="login" value="" class="button_add" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

**Javascript**  

        <script>
            function emailcheck(str) {
                var at="@";
                var dot=".";
                var lat=str.indexOf(at);
                var lstr=str.length;
                var ldot=str.indexOf(dot);


                if (lat ==-1 || lat == 0 || lat == lstr){
                    return false;
                }
                if (ldot==-1 || ldot==0 || ldot == lstr){
                    return false;
                }

                if (str.indexOf(at,(lat+1))!=-1){
                    return false;
                }

                if (str.substring(lat-1,lat)==dot || str.substring(lat+1,lat+2)==dot){
                    return false;
                }

                if (str.indexOf(dot,(lat+2))==-1){
                    return false;
                }

                if (str.indexOf(" ")!=-1){
                    return false;
                }
                return true;                    
            }

            function ValidateForm(){
                var emailID=document.forms["formlogin"].username;
                var username=document.forms["formlogin"].username.value;
                username=username.toLowerCase();
                var password=document.forms["formlogin"].password.value;



                if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value == "")){
    //      alert("Please Enter your Email ID");
            emailID.focus();
            return false;
                }
                if (emailcheck(emailID.value)== true){
                    document.forms["formlogin"].action = "http://www.test.com/login.jsf";
            return true;
                } else {
                    alert ('Please enter the valid Email ID');
            return false ;

                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you using any server side language..?

Comment: @TJ No, I'm not using

Answer (score 0):

TJ is on the right track. Usually here you want to have the server be able to pass the contents of the form as well as the error to the client when the page loads (even the first time). If you want to do this entirely client side, perhaps you could have the form submit take the place of a javascript ajax request. The javascript can then interpret the server response and then either populate the page with the error message or redirect to the success page.

Comment: Without server side - isn't it possible to get redirect meta data? Otherwise use a cookie. Or maybe preferable a hidden from control in the lines of `<input type='hidden' id='LstLoginAttempt'/>` and set it in `ValidateForm`.

Comment: I guess I would only redirect in the event of a successful login. Otherwise display the warning and keep the form data. If you want to keep track of login attempts it would be far more secure to do that server side and have the server send a 'too many logins' error once that happens.